# Files (nautilus) hangs at start and for searches

Tags: nautilus, 20.04

I've been running Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 19.10). A recent update has caused an apparent regression in the function of the Files (nautilus) app. When I start it up, it hangs for 10+ seconds. Every time I start typing in for a search, it shows the first few characters and hangs. When I run it from the terminal, I get the following message:

```
** (org.gnome.Nautilus:29510): WARNING **: 15:22:12.729: Could not establish a connection to Tracker: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1': timed out (service_start_timeout=120000ms)
```

Is this a known problem? Is there a fix for it? Thank you.

Comment: Problem with tracker. Does it persist after restart? If yes, try resetting the database - tracker will then need to reindex.

Comment: Yes, persists after restart. Yes, I tried the tracker restart (tracker reset --hard) and the problem persists.

Comment: BTW, I got to 20.04 by way of an upgrade from 19.10.

Comment: Just for testing purposes, disable tracker fully: `systemctl --user mask tracker-store.service tracker-miner-fs.service tracker-miner-rss.service tracker-extract.service tracker-miner-apps.service tracker-writeback.service && tracker reset --hard` then reboot. If still happening, we know it is not tracker. Reenable tracker substituting `unmask` in the command above. I also have an updated system, no issues here. Still, edit your question and indicate in your question that this is an upgraded system. Yet, it worked well for some time, so I don't think the issue will be in the upgrade.

Comment: After the reboot, nautilus comes up quickly, although it still gives this error:

lsitongia@yoga:~$ nautilus

** (org.gnome.Nautilus:2976): WARNING **: 14:16:09.099: Error on getting connection: Failed to load SPARQL backend: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit tracker-store.service is masked.
Nautilus-Share-Message: 14:16:09.354: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)

I suppose that error is expected, right?

Comment: OK, that is what I also have (I permanently disable tracker), so at least you the issue is with tracker. You could enable tracker again and if it still persists, I suggest making temporary new account to see if the issue is there as well. If yes, then I probably would attempt purging and reinstalling tracker

Comment: Okay. Thanks a bunch for your help, @vanadium. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @Leonard Dit it go away? I have a brand new Dell XPS 17 and I my Nautilus (Ubuntu 22.04) hangs for a few seconds when I search, after which it seems to be working fine. I never had this problem on my older laptops. I was worried I might have some SSD problems, but you gave me hope. I hope you see this and reply back. Thanks.

Comment: @conualfy, I haven't look at this for some time. I'm running Ubuntu 21.10, which is running tracker3. It is running now. I don't have any trouble with it.

Comment: For those coming later here, I have created a bug report, please also reach there for an official fix, too.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1982581

Answer (score 0):

delete both `~/.cache/tracker` and `~/.cache/tracker3`